# How to check if a particular WordPress plugin is activated, in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm using a plugin and a bit of PHP code in the theme of my WP blog to put ads where I want them.  This is an example of the code:

```
<?php echo adrotate_ad(4); ?>
```

Not too complicated but...

When the plugin is deactivated, this of course, returns a warning when trying to load the page.

I'm guessing I need a conditional statement that says if adrotate_ad(4) is not there then ignore the command?

edited:

So, trying to piece it together, would it be something like this?

```
<? 
if (function_exists('adrotate_ad(4)')) {
echo adrotate_ad(4);
} else {

} 
?>
```

What would be after "else"?

edited:

OK, I figured it out!  Thanks for the help.  Now, I'd just like to know if this is the best way for me to return nothing if the plugin is disabled:

```
<? 
if (function_exists('adrotate_ad')) {
echo adrotate_ad(4);
} else {
print "";
} 
?>
```

This produces the results I want but I don't know if it's proper.

Comment: Did you do some research or tried something?

Comment: Yeah, I've been reading and researching.  Have tried a few things but nothing has worked.  Don't even know if I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

[function_exists()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.function-exists.php) is what you need.